# Failing to exclude one URI from Spring Security protection on a POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a `HttpSecurity` like following:

```
http
   .exceptionHandling().and()
   .anonymous().and()
   .servletApi().and()
   .headers().cacheControl().and().and()
   .authorizeRequests()
       // Need authentication sur POST
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
       // Allow anonymous resource requests
       .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
   // Custom Token based authentication based on the header previously given to the client
   .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
   // Filtre pour gérer la clef d'api
   .addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyFilter(), StatelessAuthenticationFilter.class)
   // Filtre pour ajouter les headers nécessaires à la consommation par les différents clients
   .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ApiKeyFilter.class);
```

The problem is that i need to be able to `POST` on `/user` without getting a `403 Forbidden` response. So I wanted to add a rule to allow anonymous requests on `/user` with `POST`.

I used this `antMatcher`:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").anonymous()
```

but problem is that I don't know where to add this, I tried before `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").anonymous()` and after, but seems like it's ignored since I still get a `403`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the rule before `antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()`. Also, since [*CSRF*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection is enabled by default, you should either disable it or provide a *CSRF Token* in your `POST` request. Here i'm just disabling the CSRF:

```
// Same as before
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll()
    // Need authentication sur POST
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated()
    // Allow anonymous resource requests
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
.and
.csrf().disable();
// Same as before
```

You can read more about CSRF on [Spring Security Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf).